# Android Studio: Nested Library dependency

Tags: android, build, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have a project like this:

```
Project
|
--Lib1
|
--Lib2
   |
   --Lib1
--Lib3
   |
   --Lib1
```

Lib1 is a common dependency for Project, Lib2, and Lib3. How should I configure the build.gradle files?

Answer (score 1):

For the projects dependent on Lib1 you should add it as a dependency in the following way:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':Lib1')
}
```

This specific case is available in gradle user guide [Section 7.3.3. Dependencies between projects](https://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html#sec:examples) or you can find a more comprehensive description of dependencies declarations in [Section 51.4. Module Dependencies](https://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#moduleDependencies)

Comment: this method does not work. Because linker make error duplicate dex file.

Comment: Is this duplicate dex file somehow related to your build? I.e. is it one of the artifacts produced by your build or something your build takes dependency on?